# textbox visible on dropdown textchange jquery asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, html

This is my script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#txtfrom").hide();
    $("#txtto").hide();
    $("#txtvenue").hide();
    $("#drdsearch").text == "Venue Name"(function () {
        $("#txtfrom").hide();
        $("#txtto").hide();
        $("#txtvenue").show();
    });
    $("#drdsearch").text == "Date"(function () {
        $("#txtfrom").show();
        $("#txtto").show();
        $("#txtvenue").hide();
    });
});
```

These are my controls

```html
<div>
    <p style="margin-top:-24px;">
        <b style="font-size:16px; margin-left:180px;">Search By:</b>
    </p>
    <select id="drdsearch" style="margin-top:-39px; margin-left:300px; height:30px; width:200px; font-size:12px;">
        <option>Default</option>
        <option>Venue Name</option>
        <option>Date</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div style="margin-left:300px">
    <p style="font-family: Verdana">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtvenue" runat="server" CssClass="txttopborder font" ng-model="venue" Text="" placeholder="venue" Height="30" Width="200"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtfrom" runat="server" style="margin-left:-300px;" CssClass="txttopborder font" ng-model="from" placeholder="From Date" Text="" Height="30" Width="200"></asp:TextBox>
        <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="clndrfrom" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtfrom" Format="dd-MM-yyyy"></ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtto" runat="server" CssClass="txttopborder font" ng-model="to" Text="" placeholder="To Date" Height="30" Width="200"></asp:TextBox>
        <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="clndrto" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtto" Format="dd-MM-yyyy"></ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
        <%-- <button type="button" ng-click="Addrecord(x)" style="height:30px; width:50px;" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary active" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Detailsmodel"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" style="font-size:20px;"></i></button> --%>
    </p>
</div>
```

I am creating a web app in which i have given 3 options to a user from my dropdown list
1) Default
2) Venue Name
3) Date

By default, `Default` is selected and if a user selects venue name `txtvenue` should be visible and `txtfrom`,`txtto` hide,

If a user selects Date  `txtvenue` should be hidden and `txtfrom`,`txtto visible

I added this script on my page

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`

However all the controls are visible and nothing is happening on dropdown text change.

Comment: I suggest you to give value to each option

Answer (score 2):

Use **`change()`** event.

Based on the selected value you can `hide` and `show` respected inputs.

And you're missing drop-down options values.

In my example,

- I've given values to drop-down and those values as id of text-boxes.
- Use drop-down values as `#id` selector to `show` respective text-boxes.
- By default, I've hide all the text-boxes, you can do as per your need.

Example

```
$('#select').change(function(){
   if($(this).val == "txtvenue")
   {
     //Show textboxes
   }
});
```

```js
$('#drdsearch').change(function(){
   $('input').hide();
   $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="drdsearch" style="margin-top:-39px; margin-left:300px; height:30px; width:200px; font-size:12px;">
        <option value="default">Default</option>
        <option value="venue">Venue Name</option>
        <option value="date">Date</option>
    </select>

<input type="text" id="default" value="default"/>
<input type="text" id="venue" value="value"/>
<input type="text" id="date" value="date"/>
```

Comment: I was writing answer and you posted. Hard luck. 1+

Comment: I think There is something wrong with this script 

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Yes may be, it's not showing 404, you can use the one as I've used in my example. And try to make your jQuery code as shorter as you can.

Comment: Ok I am Trying this example

Answer (score 0):

I think you need write Events on the Click for example. Because this

```
$(document).ready(function () {})
```

call only when page is ready

If u want get User events, u need write something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#drdsearch").onChange(function(e){
        //this logic
        if( $(this).val() == "Venue Name") {
            $("#txtfrom").hide();
            $("#txtto").hide();
            $("#txtvenue").show();
        }
        if($(this).val() == "Date") {
            $("#txtfrom").show();
            $("#txtto").show();
            $("#txtvenue").hide();
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: I think There Is something Wrong With this script

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: `<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#txtfrom").attr('readonly', true);
            $("#txtto").attr('readonly', true);
            $("#txtvenue").attr('readonly', true);       
    });
</script>`

I am Not that new in jquery (this function is not executing)

Comment: On the your site try check console.log($) this work? What is output?

Comment: What? can you explain what it is actually i am very new in jquery

Comment: Open browser console, in the him go to Tab Console. And write console.log($)

Answer (score 0):

Here you can also try this

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#txtfrom").hide();
    $("#txtto").hide();
    $("#txtvenue").hide();
   
    
    $("#drdsearch").change(function(){
    var drp = $(this).val();
    if(drp == 1){
    $("#txtfrom").hide();
    $("#txtto").hide();
    $("#txtvenue").hide();
    }else if(drp == 2){
    $("#txtvenue").show();
    $("#txtfrom").hide();
    $("#txtto").hide();
    }else{
    $("#txtfrom").show();
    $("#txtto").show();
    $("#txtvenue").hide();
    }
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="drdsearch">
        <option value = "1">Default</option>
        <option value = "2">Venue Name</option>
        <option value = "3">Date</option>
    </select>

<input type="textbox" id = "txtfrom" placeholder="TxtFrom">
<input type="textbox" id = "txtto" placeholder="TxtTo">
<input type="textbox" id = "txtvenue" placeholder="Venue">
```